# How to determine the position of the own create shortcuts

Tags: java, android

I use the code to create a shortcut, and how can I get it in the position of the desktop. this is my create code:

```
Intent addIntent=new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
Parcelable icon=Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.mipmap.img01); 
Intent myIntent=new Intent(context, Main2Activity.class);

addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "test01");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, myIntent);
context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

I'm sure it's position to create a animation on desktop